# Java: dynamic properties file

Tags: java, spring, properties, quartz-scheduler, properties-file

I'm working on a project that uses the Quartz scheduler.  I would like to configure Quartz to use the RAM Job Store for my local environment and use the persistent Job Store for all other environments.  This project already has different properties files for our various environments, so seems like it should be simple enough, but I have run into a problem.

We have one master properties file `(web-spring-config.properties)` that pulls in the property for the appropriate environment by doing the following:
`some.property=${my.property.value}`

But for Quartz, there are different properties to be configured based upon the different Job Store type.  So, for example, to configure the persistent job store, I would need the following properties:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold= 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.DB2v8Delegate
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=myDS
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QUARTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
```

But, if I want to switch this to use the RAM Job Store, then `org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix` property (plus a few others) are actually not allowed in the properties file **at all**.  Even providing a blank value will break Quartz, as it gets a `NoSuchMethodException` when it tries to set the blank value.

I'm kind of at a loss as to what to do here.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.